# Having issue with looping through all records

Tags: sql, vb.net, foreach

I need to loop through records of a specific database (currently there are only 3 records) and look at various cells within each row for specific dates. If the date is WITHIN 30 days a reminder is to come up noting something is coming due within 'x' days.

If the due date is PAST then a secondary reminder comes up to tell me the item is 'x' days past due.

I am getting the reminders of coming due or past due but it is only looking at the first record. It is not looping and reading the remaining records. Can someone assist me in advising where or how the `for each` loop is inserted in the below code please or even if `for each` is the proper loop syntax.?

```
    Private Sub MedCertExpire()
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim reader As SqlDataReader

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.Connection = New SqlConnection With {
        .ConnectionString = My.MySettings.Default.PETS_DatabaseConnectionString
    }
    cmd.Connection.Open()

    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT EMPLOYEE_FIRST_NAME 
                            , DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), PHYSICAL_DATE) AS PHYSICAL_EXPIRES
                            , DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), CDL_EXPIRE_DATE) AS CDL_EXPIRES
                            , DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), TWIC_EXPIRES) AS TWIC_EXPIRES
                            , DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), PASSPORT_EXPIRES) AS PASSPORT_EXPIRES
                            , DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), ANNUAL_REVIEW_DATE) AS ANNUAL_REVIEW
                         FROM EMPLOYEE_TABLE"

    Try
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        Dim yName As String
        Dim yMedCert As Integer
        Dim yCDL As Integer
        Dim yTWIC As Integer
        Dim yPass As Integer
        Dim yRev As Integer

        With reader
            .Read()

            yName = .GetString(0)
            yMedCert = .GetInt32(1)
            yCDL = .GetInt32(2)
            yTWIC = .GetInt32(3)
            yPass = .GetInt32(4)
            yRev = .GetInt32(5)

            Select Case yMedCert
                Case Is <= 0
                    Call New MessageBoxMedCertExp(yName, yMedCert).ShowDialog()
                Case Is <= 30
                    Call New MessageBoxMedCert(yName, yMedCert).ShowDialog()
            End Select

            Select Case yCDL
                Case Is <= 0
                    Call New MessageBoxCDLExp(yName, yCDL).ShowDialog()
                Case Is <= 30
                    Call New MessageBoxCDL(yName, yCDL).ShowDialog()
            End Select

            Select Case yTWIC
                Case Is <= 0
                    Call New MessageBoxTWICExp(yName, yTWIC).ShowDialog()
                Case Is <= 30
                    Call New MessageBoxTWIC(yName, yTWIC).ShowDialog()
            End Select

            Select Case yPass
                Case Is <= 0
                    Call New MessageBoxPassExp(yName, yPass).ShowDialog()
                Case Is <= 30
                    Call New MessageBoxPassport(yName, yPass).ShowDialog()
            End Select

            Select Case yRev
                Case Is <= 0
                    Call New MessageBoxEmployeeReviewEXP(yName, yRev).ShowDialog()
                Case Is <= 30
                    Call New MessageBoxEmployeeReview(yName, yRev).ShowDialog()
            End Select

            Return
        End With

        reader.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex)
    End Try

    cmd.Connection.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to use While reader.Read instead With

Comment: Yep, That resolved the issue. Thanks.